# Why do redux-thunks need to be bound to dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I think I am missing a fundamental piece of understanding here. I am aware that in order for an action to be created and thus set off the redux chain of events, the action creator must be invoked using `dispatch`.

However, when we have a redux-thunk which returns a function which will call `dispatch` on our action creator, why must the redux-thunk also be called with `dispatch`?

For example take the following redux-thunk:

```
function savePerson(person: Person) {
    return async (dispatch: any) => {
        delete person.cars;
        let newPerson = await axios.post('/api/people/addPeron', person);
        dispatch(addPersonSuccess(person));
    }
}
```

Calling this savePerson function without `dispatch` does not set off the redux flow, and I don't understand why considering the function it returns calls our action creator with `dispatch`. Can anybody clarify what I seem to be missing here?

Comment: think of this as another reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All redux middleware follows the same general layout:

`const middleware => store => next => action => next(action);`

> Why must the redux-thunk also be called with `dispatch`?

Like you correctly pointed out in your first paragraph, for an action/thunk to be evaluated by the redux middleware chain, it must be `dispatch`ed by the calling code.

I think the misunderstanding comes in here:

> "...when we have a redux-thunk which returns a function which will
>   call dispatch on our action creator...".

While it is correct that the returned function dispatches an action, it is only half the story. Technically, you are dispatching *twice*: first `savePerson` and later `addPersonSuccess`. The former being a thunk and the latter, most likely, being a plain action.

Now, let's consider the current `redux-thunk` [source code](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/4f96ec0239453623adde857b7e7ad8c4f2897bf1/src/index.js):

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

...

export default thunk;
```

Once you dispatch `savePerson`, the middleware recognizes your action as a function. It then injects `dispatch` as the first argument to later allow dispatching of other actions. Up until now, `dispatch` has not been invoked on your `addPersonSuccess` action. Only after your asynchronous call to add a person will the dispatch be called on `addPersonSuccess`.

I like to think of this as passing the redux context along in the thunk (dispatch, getState, etc).

References

- http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html
- https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk